# wrapping titles and sections around figures

Tags: floats, wrap

I need to do this kind of layout on LaTeX, but I have no idea how I could wrap figures around titles. Does anyone know of any way to do this ? Or would someone happen to know a **template** to do just what you can see on the drawing I uploaded ?

Thanks a lot :)

[image]

Comment: Package `wrapfig`, for example or doing it manually ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Not sure the `wrapfig`package allow me to wrap arround sections, or at least I never used it this way. It never occured to me it could do just that. Do you know a template that resembles what I want to do ?

Comment: There's not a 'template' for anything -- 'templates' are bad, in most cases

Comment: I think my CV template is pretty good and it would have been a pain in the ass to learn to use the framework for 20 hours before getting my CV... So I think templates can be good. For this however, I think I'll try to use wrapfig, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use short titles so that the images don't show up in the table of contents.  The macro `\sectioncalc` computers `\titlewidth` to be used for section titles.  (The section number is not included.)  A lot depends on how wide your titles are and how big the images (and how you want them placed relative to the titles).  And you don't HAVE to use `\maketitle`.

The 16pt is a bit of a kludge, but none of the lengths I found in `\section` and `\@startsection` worked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength\titlewidth

\def\sectioncalc{\settowidth{\titlewidth}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\thesection}%
  \titlewidth=\dimexpr\textwidth-\titlewidth-16pt\relax}% \@tempskipa=18pt

\title{\parbox{\textwidth}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}}%
  \hfill\parbox[c]{2in}{\textbf{This is a multiline title}}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\setcounter{section}{21}
\section[First Secdtion]{\sectioncalc\parbox[b]{\titlewidth}{First Section
  \hfill\raisebox{-0.5\height}[0.5\height][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}}}}
\subsection{First Subsection}

\hangindent=-2.2in
\hangafter=-2
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: text area]